# Flutter DataTable remove extra padding

Tags: flutter

I want to display some data in a `DataTable`, i have 9 columns, all of them are number except the first one.

The problem i'm having is, i only see the first 5 columns, not because data are too long, but because there are a lot of space between every column.

[image]

Is there a way to make the DataColumn wrap the data with a padding i choose?
This is my code:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('DataTable Sample'),
  ),
  body: Container(
    child: DataTable(columns: <DataColumn>[
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('Name'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('A'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('B'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('C'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('D'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('E'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('F'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('G'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('H'),
          ),
        ], rows: <DataRow>[
          DataRow(cells: [
            DataCell(Text('1 Boston')),
            DataCell(Text('3')),
            DataCell(Text('3')),
            DataCell(Text('7')),
            DataCell(Text('1')),
            DataCell(Text('30')),
            DataCell(Text('8')),
            DataCell(Text('+2')),
            DataCell(Text('-22')),
          ]),
          DataRow(cells: [
            DataCell(Text('2 London')),
            DataCell(Text('3')),
            DataCell(Text('4')),
            DataCell(Text('12')),
            DataCell(Text('44')),
            DataCell(Text('7')),
            DataCell(Text('44')),
            DataCell(Text('-98')),
            DataCell(Text('0')),
          ]),
          DataRow(cells: [
            DataCell(Text('3 Rome')),
            DataCell(Text('10')),
            DataCell(Text('50')),
            DataCell(Text('90')),
            DataCell(Text('4')),
            DataCell(Text('7')),
            DataCell(Text('33')),
            DataCell(Text('+5')),
            DataCell(Text('-61')),
          ]),
        ]
        )
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 17):

Try setting `horizontalMargin` to 0 as this value defaults to 24.0:

```
...
DataTable(
   horizontalMargin: 0,
   columnSpacing: 10,
   columns: [
...
```

Ref.[Datatable horizontalMargin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable/horizontalMargin.html) official documentation

Answer (score 13):

you can use `SingleChildScrollView` and `FittedBox` as its child.

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('DataTable Sample'),
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    child: FittedBox(
      child: DataTable(
        columns: <DataColumn>[
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('Name'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('A'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('B'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('C'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('D'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('E'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('F'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('G'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('H'),
          ),
        ],
        rows: <DataRow>[
          DataRow(cells: [
            DataCell(Text('1 Boston')),
            DataCell(Text('3')),
            DataCell(Text('3')),
            DataCell(Text('7')),
            DataCell(Text('1')),
            DataCell(Text('30')),
            DataCell(Text('8')),
            DataCell(Text('+2')),
            DataCell(Text('-22')),
          ]),
          DataRow(cells: [
            DataCell(Text('2 London')),
            DataCell(Text('3')),
            DataCell(Text('4')),
            DataCell(Text('12')),
            DataCell(Text('44')),
            DataCell(Text('7')),
            DataCell(Text('44')),
            DataCell(Text('-98')),
            DataCell(Text('0')),
          ]),
          DataRow(cells: [
            DataCell(Text('3 Rome')),
            DataCell(Text('10')),
            DataCell(Text('50')),
            DataCell(Text('90')),
            DataCell(Text('4')),
            DataCell(Text('7')),
            DataCell(Text('33')),
            DataCell(Text('+5')),
            DataCell(Text('-61')),
          ]),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: FittedBox does nothing in this case as its purpose is to fit in the limiting area of the parent, while the parent is infinitely growing.

Answer (score 12):

Yes. Lately flutter team merged an update to this Widget. It is now only in the "master" channel (You are probably on "stable"), to switch run `flutter channel master` and then `flutter upgrade` in the terminal. After doing so you can control the space between each column by setting the `columnSpacing` parameter of `DataTable`. For further information check out this closed [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/33628)

Comment: I thought this wasn't working at first as I was developing on `Flutter For Web` and if there is more space to use, it will spread your columns out appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing **columnSpacing** parameter inside your 'DataTable()' function, it seems to accept it,
The default value is 56, reducing it will cramp the columns and increasing it will spread data out

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Table](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html) instead of DataTable. For further reference - [video](https://youtu.be/_lbE0wsVZSw).

This is how you can use it:

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('DataTable Sample')),
    body: Container(
      child: Table(
        columnWidths: {0:FractionColumnWidth(.2)},
        children: [
        TableRow(
          children: [
            Text("Name",),
            Text("A",textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text("B",textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text("A",textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text("B",textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text("A",textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text("B",textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text("A",textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text("B",textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          ]
         ),
         TableRow(
          children: [
            Text("1 Boston",),
            Text('3',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text('3',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text('7',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text('1',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text('30',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text('8',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text('+2',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text('-22',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          ]
         ),
         TableRow(
          children: [
            Text('2 London',),
            Text('3',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text('4',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text('12',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text('44',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text('7',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text('44',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text('-98',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            Text('0',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          ]
         ),
        TableRow(
          children: [
              Text('3 Rome'),
              Text('10',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
              Text('50',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
              Text('90',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
              Text('4',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
              Text('7',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
              Text('33',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
              Text('+5',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
              Text('-61',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          ]
         ),
        ]
      ),
    )
  ),
```

Comment: I got the same thing, i can't see the whole table, and i want to use `DataTable` because of some functionalities like `Sorting` data.

Comment: He Asked question about DataTable not about Table

Answer (score 1):

Currently, even I am stuck with the same issue, but I have found an alternative to this problem where **you** **can see** all your **9 columns**. Have a look if it can help you.

> use **SingleChildScrollView** to scroll the Datatable horizontally

```
Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(title: Text('DataTable Sample')),
body: data()
)
```

> create a function outside "Widget build(BuildContext context) {}" as given below

```
SingleChildScrollView data() { 
return SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Container(
child: DataTable(columns: <DataColumn>[
      DataColumn(
        label: Text('Name'),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text('A'),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text('B'),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text('C'),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text('D'),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text('E'),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text('F'),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text('G'),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text('H'),
      ),
    ], rows: <DataRow>[
      DataRow(cells: [
        DataCell(Text('1 Boston')),
        DataCell(Text('3')),
        DataCell(Text('3')),
        DataCell(Text('7')),
        DataCell(Text('1')),
        DataCell(Text('30')),
        DataCell(Text('8')),
        DataCell(Text('+2')),
        DataCell(Text('-22')),
      ]),
      DataRow(cells: [
        DataCell(Text('2 London')),
        DataCell(Text('3')),
        DataCell(Text('4')),
        DataCell(Text('12')),
        DataCell(Text('44')),
        DataCell(Text('7')),
        DataCell(Text('44')),
        DataCell(Text('-98')),
        DataCell(Text('0')),
      ]),
      DataRow(cells: [
        DataCell(Text('3 Rome')),
        DataCell(Text('10')),
        DataCell(Text('50')),
        DataCell(Text('90')),
        DataCell(Text('4')),
        DataCell(Text('7')),
        DataCell(Text('33')),
        DataCell(Text('+5')),
        DataCell(Text('-61')),
      ]),
    ]
    )
  ),
  }
```

> Let me know if it solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

To remove the space between every column, you can change the value of columnSpacing which is 56 by default.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet showcasing how to do this.