# DataTable overflow in Flutter

Tags: flutter, datatable, flutter-layout

**Goal and Problem:** I am trying to create a checkout page for my app with the itemization through a DataTable widget. I get an overflow error of 13 pixels though:

> A RenderFlex overflowed by 23 pixels on the right. The relevant
> error-causing widget was DataTable

What is causing this issue and what is the remedy?

**Picture:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
Expanded(
            flex: 8,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: DataTable(
                columns: [
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text(
                      '#',
                      style: GoogleFonts.ubuntuMono(
                          color: colorPalette.chooseColor('orange'),
                          fontSize: 17),
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text(
                      'Menu Item',
                      style: GoogleFonts.ubuntuMono(
                          color: colorPalette.chooseColor('orange'),
                          fontSize: 17),
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text(
                      'Item Price',
                      style: GoogleFonts.ubuntuMono(
                          color: colorPalette.chooseColor('orange'),
                          fontSize: 17),
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text(
                      '-',
                      style: GoogleFonts.ubuntuMono(
                          color: colorPalette.chooseColor('orange'),
                          fontSize: 17),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
                rows: [
                  DataRow(cells: [
                    DataCell(
                      Text(
                        '1',
                        style: GoogleFonts.ubuntuMono(
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: colorPalette.chooseColor('darkGrey'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Text(
                        'dish name',
                        style: GoogleFonts.ubuntuMono(
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: colorPalette.chooseColor('darkGrey'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Center(
                          child: Text('\$\$\$',
                              style: GoogleFonts.ubuntuMono(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 15,
                                color: colorPalette.chooseColor('darkGrey'),
                              ))),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.cancel_sharp,
                          color: colorPalette.chooseColor('darkOrange'),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 6):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You use use `SingleChildScrollView` with `Axis.horizontal` wrap `DataTable` 
code snippet

```
child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: DataTable(
            columns: [
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 8,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  child: DataTable(
                    columns: [
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text(
                          '#',
                          style: GoogleFonts.ubuntuMono(
                              //color: colorPalette.chooseColor('orange'),
                              fontSize: 17),
                        ),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text(
                          'Menu Item',
                          style: GoogleFonts.ubuntuMono(
                              //color: colorPalette.chooseColor('orange'),
                              fontSize: 17),
                        ),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text(
                          'Item Price',
                          style: GoogleFonts.ubuntuMono(
                              //color: colorPalette.chooseColor('orange'),
                              fontSize: 17),
                        ),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text(
                          '-',
                          style: GoogleFonts.ubuntuMono(
                              //color: colorPalette.chooseColor('orange'),
                              fontSize: 17),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                    rows: [
                      DataRow(cells: [
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            '1',
                            style: GoogleFonts.ubuntuMono(
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              fontSize: 15,
                              //color: colorPalette.chooseColor('darkGrey'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            'dish name',
                            style: GoogleFonts.ubuntuMono(
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              fontSize: 15,
                              //color: colorPalette.chooseColor('darkGrey'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                          Center(
                              child: Text('\$\$\$',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.ubuntuMono(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    //color: colorPalette.chooseColor('darkGrey'),
                                  ))),
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.cancel_sharp,
                              //color: colorPalette.chooseColor('darkOrange'),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for putting that together. I should probably just use list tiles then since scrolling wouldn't look professional there.

Answer (score 6):

per this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57177294/13795508

Using FittedBox() solved this for me instead of the scroll view which could be useful under other circumstances.